# Rails simple form problem - How to put hidden input field last?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

How do I change the order of the input element that simple form generate?

Because the hidden checkbox does block for clicking the label.

My simple_form code:

```
<label>
  <span>Company<b></b></span>
  <%= f.check_box :company_is_true %>
</label>
```

The form simple form generate:

```
    <label>
        <span>Company<b>0</b></span>
       <input type="hidden" value="0" name="search[company_is_true]">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="search[company_is_true]" id="search_company_is_true">
      </label>
```

That I want to generate, that works when clicking on label:

```
<label>
    <span>Company<b>0</b></span>

<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="search[company_is_true]" id="search_company_is_true">
    <input type="hidden" value="0" name="search[company_is_true]">
  </label>
```

Comment: You should not put the hidden field after the checkbox. If you noticed checkbox and input field has same name. Purpose of hidden field is if checkbox is not checked no input from chackbox is passed in form, and elements with same name, latest element gets the value. So, if you didn't check the checkbox, value 0 is passed from hidden field, but if you check it, value one is paased from checkbox.

Comment: Is there any tricks, that can apply click functionality to the label if it is not possiable to move the hidden input field

Comment: And about the HTML semantic, you won't need to have the span tag elements inside the label.

Comment: Please be more specific about your last comment. Click on label to do what? Move the hidden field to where?

Comment: The user should be able to click on the label to check and uncheck the checkbox

Comment: @Kleber - Move the input field as in the last example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to add a comment to the list of comments, but in response to:

> The user should be able to click on the label to check and uncheck the checkbox – Rails
>   beginner 1 hour ago

It's not the checkbox that prevents the user from clicking on that label, it's the lack of the for="" in

```html
<label>
  <span>Company<b></b></span>
  <%= f.check_box :company_is_true %>
</label>
```

Either use <%= f.label %> as agmcleod mentioned, or add a for="" to the label:

```html
<label for="search_company_is_true">
  <span>Company<b></b></span>
  <%= f.check_box :company_is_true %>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

In a traditional html form, it should be structured something like this:

```
<label for="name">Name: </label>
<input type="text" name="name" />
```

The for attribute connects it to a field with either a name attribute or id attribute with that value you use in for. To do this in rails, use the following:

```
<%= f.label :company_is_true, 'Company' %>
<%= f.check_box :company_is_true %>
```